# Unknown Posts added to my wordpress website from nowhere

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I have a WordPress website.
recently I noticed that every hour one post added to my website from nowhere and I don't know why. What is the problem? what should I do?

Comment: Assuming you did not add a plugin that is adding posts and you are not technical I would suggest contacting your host, its possible your site could have been hacked.